# TypeError:undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, react-native

Getting TypeError:undefined is not a constructor.

Here is my **Code**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';

export default function App() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <appStackNavigator />
     </View>
      );
  }

  const appStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({
    Login: { Screen: LoginScreen },

  });


   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container:
     {
       backgroundColor: '#AA00FF',
       flex: 1,
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
     },
   });
```

Here is the **Error** I got:

```
TypeError:undefined is not a constructor(evaluating'new_reactNavigation.StackNavigator({Login:{Screen:_LoginScreen.LoginScreen}})')
```

Please help to debug.

Edit: (post was mostly code, so added some lines in support of question)

Comment: Please check if you use export default in your LoginScreen file. You have to use export, not export default. If you used export default, you have to use -- import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';

Comment: I tried both way and ended with same error, couldn't find out why

Comment: Please try lower case. Login: { screen: LoginScreen } or Login: LoginScreen

Comment: shouldn't you use `createStackNavigator` from `react-navigation-stack` instead of using `new StackNavigator(...)`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html